# Get style of image on onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the code:

```
<ul id="carousel">
    <li><a class="group cboxElement" href="Images/AiringCupboard0_2.jpg">
        <img src="Images/2013042517364073_AiringCupboard0_2.jpg" alt="Image not found" title="AiringCupboard0_2.jpg"
            style="width: 144px; height: 192px; opacity: 1">
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="group cboxElement" href="Images/AiringCupboard0_3.jpg">
        <img src="Images/2013042517364073_AiringCupboard0_3.jpg" alt="Image not found" title="AiringCupboard0_3.jpg"
            style="width: 144px; height: 192px; opacity: 1">
    </a></li>
</ul>
```

To fetch particular name I tried
**javascript**

```
 var img_name = document.getElementsByClassName('cboxPhoto')[0].nameProp;
 var $img_panel_id = $('#carousel').find('li a img' + img_name);
 $img_panel_id.parent().attr('style');
```

Lets say img_name is `AiringCupboard0_3.jpg` then how can I fetch style of that image tag

Comment: where are elements `.cboxPhoto`?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar it used to fetch the image name..

Comment: @Deb - why you downvote my long back accepted answers

Comment: @JqueryKing sorry But I didnot do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the image by its titles ...

```
$("#carousel").click(function() {
    $(this).find('img[title="AiringCupboard0_3.jpg"]').attr("style");
});
```

Comment: Nice to hear that from you! :D .. So set it as resolve, so someone who has the same problem could notice it! :)

Comment: sure..last question after this m getting `  $img_panel_id "width: 144px; height: 192px; opacity: 1;` now I want to add css into that so ` $img_panel_id.css('opacity', '0.5');` I have done this but it doesnot found any css property into that..any mistake over there?

Comment: try `$($img_panel_id).css('opacity', '0.5');`

Comment: `var $img_panel_id = $('#carousel').find('li a img[title="' + img_name + '"]')[0].style;` and then access `$img_panel_id.opacity`

Comment: Good, yeah, another way to do this! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var getCarouselImg = document.querySelectorAll('#carousel li');
for(var i = 0; i < getCarouselImg.length; i++){
    getCarouselImg[i].onclick = function(){
        console.log(this.querySelector('img').getAttribute('style'));
    }
}
```

Comment: It is generally better to explain what you have done with your code. Be constructive.